# Payment Request Applepay в iframe

Tags: javascript, apple, платежи

Есть страница с реализованным payment request api, в ней есть кнопка Applepay и все работает. Но как только страница встраивается в iframe, происходит ошибка  **SecurityError: Trying to start an Apple Pay session from a document with an different security origin than its top-level frame**.

Атрибут allowpaymentrequest='true' имеется

Обе страницы https.

**Код example.com:**

```
          const applePayMethod = {
                supportedMethods: "https://apple.com/apple-pay",
                data: {
                    version: 3,
                    merchantIdentifier: "somemerchantid",
                    merchantCapabilities: ["supports3DS",],
                    supportedNetworks: ["masterCard", "visa"],
                    countryCode: "US",
                },
            };

            const paymentDetails = {
                total: {
                    label: "My Merchant",
                    amount: { value: "27.50", currency: "USD" },
                },
            }

            try {
                const request = new PaymentRequest([applePayMethod], paymentDetails, {});

                const response = await request.show();
                const status = processResponse(response);
                response.complete(status);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
```

** Код страницы example-with-iframe.com/ с iframe: **

`<iframe allowpaymentrequest='true' src="https://example.com/" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

Apple Pay не работает в iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по тому, что Apple Pay работает на основном домене, домен есть в списке разрешенных для оплаты в https://developer.apple.com. Возможно, домен в iframe в него не входит.
UPD: У меня, при использовании эквайринга Сбера, верифицировать домен нет возможности, поэтому пришлось сделать открытие сберовской формы оплаты в новом табе (окне). Пофиксить ошибку, подобную вашей, некостыльного решения похоже нет.